# Implementing a timer in Traveller game

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

This problem is a continuation of what I started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292934/functional-banana-traveller-game-intriguing-and-maddening).
I'm using the [asteroid](https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Asteroids.hs) example as a model to work from.

The problem I want to talk about here is the one of a timer. The asteroids example uses the `event0` function to make one, which relies on the `Graphics.UI.WX` library. I don't want to use WX for this project. Could someone tell me what `event0` is doing generally, so that I can figure out what I need to do to make a similar function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind reactive-banana to an external event-based framework, be it WX or any other, have a look at the `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks` module.

The `event0` function from reactive-banana-wx is just a thin wrapper over the [`fromAddHandler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/latest/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Frameworks.html#v%3afromAddHandler) function from said module. The example code for reactive-banana demonstrates its use.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Heinrich. I have re-visited the slot machine example for instruction on how to use fromAddHandler.

Comment: Also at first glance, ActuatePause.hs looks instructive as well.