# Functional Banana Traveller - Input Handling

Tags: haskell, stm, frp, reactive-banana

This is a sub-problem from my [Traveller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292934/functional-banana-traveller-game-intriguing-and-maddening) project.

I've put together the rudementary code that will handle input. It works, until I introduce a `TChan` to the mix. Below is the working code, with an example of how to use it. Then, I will change it and explain why I am doing so. Then, I'll talk about the problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import Control.Monad.STM (STM,atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TChan
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks


data Planet = Vulcan
            | Mars
            | Terra
                deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

data Command = Move Planet
             | Look
             | Quit
             | Null
                deriving Show

makeNetworkDescription :: AddHandler (Maybe Command) -> IO EventNetwork
makeNetworkDescription addCommandEvent = compile $ do
   eInput <- fromAddHandler addCommandEvent
   let eCommand = filterJust eInput 
       bCommand = stepper Null eCommand 
   eCommandChanged <- changes bCommand

reactimate $ (\n -> appendFile "output.txt" ("Command is " ++ show n)) <$>  
eCommandChanged
```

Executing the following in `ghci` will demonstrate that this works.

```
(addCommandEvent,fireCommand) <- newAddHandler :: IO (AddHandler (Maybe Command),Maybe Command -> IO ())
networkDescr <- makeNetworkDescription addCommandEvent
actuate networkDescr
return (Just $ Look) >>= fireCommand
```

So, now I have have the basic mechanism in place, I want to start building it out. This is going to be a multiplayer game. The first step in addressing this as far the the input handling goes is getting input from a `TChan`. The idea being, all players will write to this `TChan`, and each command will be processed in the order it arrived.

So I added a new function 'inputFrame'

```
inputFrame :: TChan Command -> IO ()
inputFrame commandChannel = do
   (addCommandEvent,fireCommand) <- newAddHandler
   networkDescr <- makeNetworkDescription addCommandEvent
   actuate networkDescr
   forkIO $ forever (atomically $ tryReadTChan commandChannel) >>= fireCommand
   return ()
```

Here is how I attempt to use it, in `ghci`.

```
commandChan <- atomically $ newTChan :: IO (TChan Command)
_ <- atomically $ writeTChan commandChan Look
```

`output.txt` doesn't get written to. `commandChan` is being read, as I check to see if it becomes empty after populating it. Is it obvious what I'm doing wrong? If not, how may I go about troubleshooting the problem? Also, for my intended purposes, is a `TChan` the right choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *probably* wanted

```
forkIO $ forever (atomically (tryReadTChan commandChannel) >>= fireCommand)
```

but I haven't tested this. Also, at a guess, you probably will want to avoid `tryReadTChan` here. Just use plain old `readTChan`, so that you get the efficient `retry` instead of polling.